# Disable certain javascript code only to mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript code to rotate several divs using the .fadeOut .fadeIn functions and I have those same divs float on the sidebar so the position stays fixed while you scroll.  This works perfectly when  the window is larger than 980px but starts to overlap when on mobile devices.  I was wondering if someone would be able to help me out with a code to have the the scroll function not run when the window is less than 980px. Below is the script i am using to fix the sidebar while scrolling.

```
$(function(){
    var stickyRibbonTop = $('.rotate').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
            if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyRibbonTop ) {
                    $('.rotate').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
            } else {
                    $('.rotate').css({position: 'relative'});
            }
    });
```

});

The test site is am using is beta.badsentinel.com.  Please check and shrink the window size to get a better idea of what i am talking about.  The sidebar will start to overlap.

thanks in advance.

Comment: `if(document.body.clientWidth > 980)return;` should work

Answer (score 3):

Instead of setting the CSS, add and remove a class. That way you can set what each class does using media queries.

Comment: Please provide sample code. I think your answer is more like comment.

Comment: So i just made another rotate class (.rotate-mobile) and used the Media query to only apply it to max-width: 980px. I set the CSS on rotate-mobile to relative position so it doesn't stay fixed.  I am just not sure how I would apply that to the code above.  Sorry but im still a little new to javacripting.

Comment: NVM I was able to get it with just setting  the media query to max-width 980 and having the CSS on the div class with a relevant position.  Thanks alot.  Its working exactly how i wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
function widthDetect(){
if (($(window).width() <= 980  )) {
    var stickyRibbonTop = $('.rotate').offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
            if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyRibbonTop ) {
                    $('.rotate').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
            } else {
                    $('.rotate').css({position: 'relative'});
            }
    });
}}
widthDetect();
$(window).resize(function(){
    widthDetect();
});
```

and you can also do it with css media query.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 980px) { 
.rotate { position:relative !important;}
}
```